# how to know that update statement in sqlplus updated the tabel or not(from shell script)

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I need to update a table with some where conditon. If update fails then I need to insert the same.  I am using here document from a shell script to run sqlplus, please help me to find the way so I can insert in case of faliur of update.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output to a temporary file and don't forget to include stderr as well. Then you can parse the output and look for characteristics. In your SQL you can also do a

```
select "SUCCESS" from dual;
```

at the end, the shell script could look for.

```
sqlplus user@db @my_sqlfile >output 2>&1
grep "SUCCESS" output
```

sqlplus also usually writes in the output something like

```
N records updated.
```

So you can also check if there are as many updates as you expect if you need this.

Just be sure to set the options in your sql file appropriately because this affects what sqlplus will spill out.

```
set term ...
```

Comment: thanks Devolus, but I am looking for solution so that I can update or insert in this sqlplus connection only.
so can I check that update updated the table from inside of sqlplus only? something like if else.

Comment: The you must use PLSQL.  You could write a tricky dynamic SQL if you need to do it purely, but that might be complicated. You should get more specific, in order to give some hints.